# Controller does not exist in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, controller

I have this error where it said that the controller [does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkaie.png)

My routes

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PasienController;  
Route::resource('/pasien', PasienController::class)->only(['index']);
```

The controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Token;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

class PasienController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $patient = null;
        if (isset($request->nik)) {
            $response = $this->patient_by_nik($request->nik);
            $data = $response->getData();
            if ($response->status() == 200) {
                if ($data->total) {
                    $patient = $data->entry[0]->resource;
                    Alert::success($response->statusText(), 'Pasien Ditemukan');
                } else {
                    Alert::error('Not Found', 'Pasien Tidak Ditemukan');
                }
            } else {
                Alert::error($response->statusText() . ' ' . $response->status());
            }
        }
        
}
```

I was trying to get data from an API and return the data

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: in Laravel 5.6 the root namespace of all controllers is defined in the `RouteServiceProvider` so you should use `'PasienController'` as the controller name instead of `PasienController::class` (which includes the namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route wrap your controller class in a bracket `[]`, like this:

`Route::resource('/pasien', [PasienController::class])->only('index');`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Route::post('/pasien', 'PasienController@index');
> ```

Update your route to follow the right format for laravel 5.6